# What's the real difference between 3GLs and 4GLs?

Tags: programming-languages

I can't find anything that is useful to determine if a language is third generation or fourth. All I find is open statements like "higher level" and "closer to English" and some sources say that they are domain specific languages like SQL and others say that they can be general purpose. I'm really confused.

If 2GLs are the Assembly languages and 5GLs are the inference languages like Prolog, how do you determine if a programming language is a 3GL or a 4GL?

Comment: No-one uses these terms in serious discourse regarding programming technologies. Forget them.

Comment: They are part of a national syllabus of computer studies.

Comment: Shame on me. I didn't know that terminology. Actually, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) has good definitions that can help you answering your question.

Comment: @mtanti: Then all the more shame on those who promulgate the syllabus.

Comment: @bacchus: No shame on you at all - these are old, old buzzwords, and those who are teaching them still do a huge disservice to their pupils.

Comment: @Marcin: The teachers don't come up with the syllabus.

Comment: @mtanti: Your comment neither contradicts what I said, nor adds any information. The fact remains that if you are being taught this, you are being taught obsolete material; if you are teaching it, you are teaching obsolete and irrelevant material; if you are devising the syllabus you are stealing time from a generation of pupils and teachers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Most* use of the terms was pure marketing -- "Oh, you're still using a *third* generation language? That's *so* last week!"

Behind that, there was a *tiny* bit of technical meaning though (at least for a little while, though many "4GLs" ignored it). The basic difference was (supposed to be that) third generation languages allowed you to manipulate only individual data items, where fourth generation languages allows you to manipulate groups of items as a group rather than individually.

Two obvious examples of this are SQL and APL. In SQL, you mostly work with sets. The result of a query is a set (not exactly a mathematical set, but at least somewhat similar). You can use and manipulate that set as a whole, merge it with other sets, etc. Until or unless you're exposing it to the outside world (e.g., with a cursor) you don't have to deal with the individual records/rows/tuples that make up that set.

In APL you get somewhat the same idea, except you're working with arrays instead of sets. To get an idea of what this means, let's assume you wanted to "rotate" an array so the currently-first element was moved to the end, and each other element was shifted ahead a spot. To do that in a typical 3GL (Fortran, Pascal, C, etc.) you'd write a loop that worked with the individual elements in the array. In APL, however, you have a single operator that will do that to the array as a whole, all in one operation. Even operations that work with individual items are generally trivial to apply to an entire array at once with the `/` operator, so (for example) the sum of all the elements in an array named `a` could be computed with `+/a` (or maybe that was `/+a` -- it's been a *long* time since I wrote any APL).

There are some pretty serious problems with the general idea of the distinction involved there though. One is that it placed a heavy emphasis on syntax -- obviously the actions involved required things like loops internally, so the distinction amounted to a syntax for an implicit loop. Another problem was that in quite a few cases you ended up with something of a blend of the two generations -- e.g., most BASICs being able to treat a string as a single thing, but requiring loops for similar operations on arrays/matrices. Finally, there was a little bit of a problem with relevance: although in a few special cases (like SQL) being able to work with a group/set/array/whatever of data as a whole really made a big difference -- but for the most part it did little to let people think and work with higher level abstractions (as was at least apparently the original intent).

That combined with a move toward languages that blurred the distinction between what was built in, and what was part of a library (or whatever). In C++, most ML-family languages, etc., it's trivial to write a function with arbitrary actions (including but not limited to loops) and attach it to an operator that's essentially indistinguishable from one that's built into the language.

It was a catchy phrase with a meaning most couldn't explain and even fewer cared about -- a prime candidate for being turned into pure marketspeak, usually translated roughly as: "you should pay me a lot for my slow, ugly, buggy CRUD application generator."

Comment: So Python's .reverse and .sort list methods make it a 4GL?

Comment: @mtanti: I doubt anybody can answer that directly -- but my inclination would be toward no. Those are really methods of a class, not operators built into the language.

Comment: btw, do you have any references for this?

Comment: @mtanti: No -- none that I can cite at the moment anyway. About the best I'd probably be able to do would be to name some of the magazines and such that I read 30 years ago or so, but I certainly don't remember specific articles or issues or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

"Language generations" were a hot buzzword in the 1980s and early 1990s. They were always ill-defined, and little used in actual academic discourse.

The terms had little meaning at the time, and none now.